# LG P500 drivers (Windows 7 x64)

Tags: drivers, android

I just purchased an [LG P500 Optimus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LG_Optimus_One#LG_Optimus_One_P500) phone (Android 2.2). Where are LG's USB drivers and sync software for this phone?

I've looked on the LG site of course and only found the firmware update tool.

[LG mobile phone support site](http://www.lg.com/in/support/mc-support/mobile-phone-support.jsp).

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I've figured it out. You need to download the mobile update tool which then lets you download the drivers, product manual and so on